# Bokeh server whitelist

Tags: python, server, tornado, bokeh

How do i start a bokeh server with a file of address that is my whitelist?

I currently launch it using

```
python -m bokeh server --host x.x.x.x:5006 --host x.x.x.x:5006 --host x.x.x.x:5006 --host x.x.x.x:5006 --host x.x.x.x:5006 --host x.x.x.x:5006 --show myapp
```

I would like it to be

```
python -m bokeh server --host whitelist.txt --show myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this feature is still not implemented in the `bokeh` command line. Some bash language can be used though. Let's say you have the list of addresses and server names in several lines inside a file "whitelist.txt", e.g.

```
some.servername.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
some.other.server.com
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
...
```

Then you can start your bokeh server with:

```
cmd="bokeh serve myapp.py --port XXXX --prefix someprefix";while read line;do cmd+=" --host $line:80"; done <whitelist.txt;eval $cmd
```

Then you are ready to reach your application in a browser:

```
http://some.other.server.com/someprefix/myapp.py
```

Comment: As the this answer correctly notes, there is nothing built in to Bokeh that will read this from a file. I would suggest this as a feature request on GH, but in fact we are trying to make it so the host whitelist is no longer needed at all.